# Parsing Wiki API content

Tags: php, wiki, wikipedia-api

I have this wiki from the API http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=%C9rythropo%EF%E9tine&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm

which I would like to retrieve the main content starting from:

```
L''''érythropoïétine''' ('''EPO''') est une [[hormone]] ......etc
```

I tried for a start to preg_replace everything from the top starting from the word "{{Chimiebox..." to the bottom "}}" using this

```
preg_replace( '/^{{(.*)}}$/sim', '', $value[0]['*'] );
```

But kind of doesn't work..does anyone know of a good way to determine the start of the content?? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, afaik the most projects use the Wikipedia Parser directly, e.g. the [Wikipedia Offline  Client Project](https://projects.fslab.de/projects/wpofflineclient/browser/trunk#mediawiki-sa-pack) at my university. Since you seem to be using php, this may the be the easiest way for you.

Comment: Thanks Zeis, seems like a whole package framework, kinda overkill as I just need to get the wiki content but nonetheless thanks, I'll see if it helps. Appreciated.

Comment: I gave you the link just for an example. No need to use it like they did.